# File copy software with graphical UI that allows automatically skips files that can't be read

Tags: windows, file-management

I have an old hard-drive that unfortunately contains a few files that can't be read. When I try to copy the 300 GB with the default Windows file copy utility it stops when it comes to a file that can't be read and thus can't be copied.

I heared that robo-copy is a command line utility that allows me to copy the files but it would be nicer to have a software with a nice UI. 
Is there one that does the job for me?

Comment: By "nice UI", do you mean "graphical UI"? If so, edit the question.

Comment: Is it acceptable if the app informs you of the first problem and you click "skip all", or does it have to run totally unattended?

Comment: @Mawg : It's completely fine when the software asks me about how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FreeFileSync](https://www.freefilesync.org/), a powerfull tool wich inform you the files that are unable to copy.

It has several features, included the portable version.

Comment: I tried to use it to sync but it seems to hang on a file it can't read instead of skipping it.